# "Равномерное" распределение обращений по датам

Tags: c#

Задача состоит в распределении обращений по датам равномерно. Первое,что пришло в голову-найти среднее значение обращений в день. Далее с помощью двух циклов присваивать свойству CreationDate  значение из массива дат(workDays). Проблема состоит в том, что в зависимости от того, в какую сторону округлить среднее количество обращений в день, за пределы массива (или листа) выходит либо индекс списка обращений, либо индекс массива рабочих дней.В чем проблема и возможно ли решить задачу альтернативным способом без использования вложенных циклов?

```
 public static float AverageAppealsCount(List<Appeal> appeals, DateTime[] workDays)
    {
        float appealsCount = appeals.Count;
        float workDaysCount = workDays.Length;
        return appealsCount / workDaysCount;

    }

    public static List<Appeal> AppealsDistributionOnDate (List<Appeal> appeals , DateTime[] workDays)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i <=workDays.Length;)
        {


                for (int j = 0; j <= appeals.Count;)
                {


                appeals[j].CreationDate = workDays[i];

                    j++;
                if ((j % Math.Ceiling(AverageAppealsCount(appeals, workDays)) == 0))
                {
                    i++;
                }

            }                    

        }
        return appeals;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное вам нужно что то вроде этого

```
public static List<Appeal> AppealsDistributionOnDate(List<Appeal> appeals,
                                                   DateTime[] workDays)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < appeals.Count; j++)     
        appeals[j].CreationDate = workDays[j % workDays.Length];

    return appeals;
}
```